# Getting undesired output while modifying list in python, when list is assigned as an array

Tags: python, matrix

```
A = [[8,5,6],
 [5,5,4],
 [11,6,8]] 

def lowertriangle(A):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            A[i][j]=A[i][j]/A[i][i]
        
    break

lowertriangle(A)

print(A)
```

I was expecting a proper division with float as output but

```
A = [[1.0,5.0,6.0],[5,5,4],[11,6,8]]
```

appeared

Can anyone help with this, i tried debugging but still am not able to figure out the error.

Comment: What's the output supposed to look like?

Comment: A= [[1.0, 0.625, 0.75], [5, 5, 4], [11, 6, 8]]

Comment: The code you posted has the `break` outside the loop, which is a syntax error. It's not clear where that is supposed to be.

Comment: The first division sets `A[0][0]` to `1.0`. In the second division, `i` is 0 and `j` is 1, so `A[i][j] = A[i][j] / A[i][i]` => `A[0][1] = A[0][1] / A[0][0]` => `A[0][1] = 5 / 1.0` => `A[0][1] = 5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the values to be calculated based on the original values in `A`, but you're updating them as you go, so the later divisions are using the changed values.

The first division sets `A[0][0]` to `1.0`.

In the second division, `i` is `0` and `j` is `1`, so:

```py
A[i][j] = A[i][j] / A[i][i]
```

is equivalent to:

```py
A[0][1] = A[0][1] / A[0][0]
```

which is equivalent to:

```py
A[0][1] = 5 / 1.0
```

and the result of that is:

```py
A[0][1] = 5.0
```

One way to solve this would be to make a new array of the right shape and size to store the results and then update that based on the original array.